# How to create Countdown timers with User Input

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web development and I want to track work of employs. So whenever a new task assigns to an employee, a manager has to add his name and given time. After adding the time it will start to countdown from a given time. And it will become red on 0. I have seen many examples but cannot implement it. I have to add items in the drop-down from javascript as well but I cannot call it. I have to add multiple employees to the list.

Comment: What does "cannot implement it" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use either bootstrap or J query date time selector and supply that date to below java script.

```
<p id="timer"></p>

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("May 30, 2018 15:16:25").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 
        60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 
        60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + 
        "h "
        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is finished, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```